# how to clear table cell imageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What is the easiest way to clear cell.imageView.image when you are reusing table cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath? The problem is when I am scrolling table and new images start to load I can still see previous images for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Show the code you have for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Then we can tell you what to fix.

Comment: Any cell formatting/design should be handled in willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:, cellForRowAtIndexPath is purely for returning the required cell as per Apple documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set placeholder image or `nil` to [imageview.image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image).